# R shiny - conditionalPanel does not show all elements

Tags: r, shiny

I have trouble understanding some odd behaviour with `conditionalPanel()`. Based on a user input a partially different message should be shown. One element should be shown in any case. See example:

```
## Only run this example in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("option", "Select option",
                  c("A", "B", "C"),
                  selected = "B"
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("test0"),
      uiOutput("test1")
    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$msg <- renderText("Some text") 

    output$test0 <- renderUI({
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.option == 'B' || input.option == 'C'",
        verbatimTextOutput("msg"),
        wellPanel(h4("Are you sure you don't want to select A?")))
      })

    output$test1 <- renderUI({
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.option == 'A'",
        verbatimTextOutput("msg"),
        wellPanel(h4("Good choice!")))
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

The obvious solution in this mini example would be to move the `verbatimTextOutput()` outside the `conditionalPanel()`, however I'd like to know if there is another way to solve this.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are defining two `verbatimTextOutput`s with the same id. Perhaps shiny's default behavior ignores the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two outputs sharing the same ID. However, you can define the same `render` function for two different outputs, what would be the solution in your case. Just assign different IDs to your `verbatimTextOutputs` and one `render` function to both of them.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("option", "Select option",
                  c("A", "B", "C"),
                  selected = "B"
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("test0"),
      uiOutput("test1")
    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$msg1 <- output$msg2 <- renderText("Some text") 

    output$test0 <- renderUI({
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.option == 'B' || input.option == 'C'",
        verbatimTextOutput("msg1"),
        wellPanel(h4("Are you sure you don't want to select A?")))
      })

    output$test1 <- renderUI({
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.option == 'A'",
        verbatimTextOutput("msg2"),
        wellPanel(h4("Good choice!")))
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just combine them into the same output

```
output$test0 <- renderUI({
  list(
    verbatimTextOutput("msg"), 
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.option == 'B' || input.option == 'C'",
      wellPanel(h4("Are you sure you don't want to select A?"))), 
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.option == 'A'",
      wellPanel(h4("Good choice!")))
  )
})
```

No need for `output$test1`. Then there will only be a single `verbatimTextOutput("msg")`